# Typo3, How can I get the MySQL query created from the query object

Tags: php, mysql, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I am new to Typo3. I am using 6.1 version of it.

I need to display the MySQL query generated from the query object. Please let me know how can I do that?

Below is the code snippet that is in my repository class.

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
$query->matching(
    $query->equals('id',intval($id))
);

return $query->execute();
```

I need to display the MySQL query before executing and returning the result of the query.

Please let me know how can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for debugging purposes?

Comment: @Xatenev, yes I want to check what is going wrong in my query as its not displaying the expected output.

Comment: @biesior, I have already checked that topic, but its not helpful to me. So please let me know if you have any other solution for my issue.

Comment: @KrishDamani the solutions described there are only available

Comment: @biesior, Okay I got it how to implement it. You meant to implement it in the core library files and then remove them after completed up with the debugging right? This is what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in extbase its **very** hard to display the last query.

you might try the normal TYPO3 way, but you have to execute the query before you can do that:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->store_lastBuiltQuery = 1;

//query

// the complete SQL-Statement
echo $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->debug_lastBuiltQuery;
```

Another way is to go into the `buildQuery(array $sql)` just before the `return statement` and add this snippet:

```
if (in_array("your_table_name", $sql['tables'])) {
    var_dump($statement);
    print_r($statement);
}
```

You can find the buildQuery method here:

```
TYPO3 ver.: 4.x: typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php
TYPO3 ver.: 6.x: typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php
```

**Edit:**
A very good method is to just misspell the column name. For example: Column is called `test`, call it `testsdffq`. The query will fail and it will show you the whole query.

Comment: I am not getting how to implement this. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Okay I tried to implement the second way. You meant to implement it in the core library files and then remove them after completed up with the debugging right? This is what I did.

Comment: @KrishDamani Yea exactly :). You have to put it into the core because the query is built there. You have to get the raw query before anything else happens :).

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.

Make sure the following is set in localconf.php:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['sqlDebug'] = '1';   
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['debug'] = '1';
```

try

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->SELECTquery('*', 'tx_xmluploader_xml_import_tree', 'xml_import_id='.$xml_import_id);
t3lib_div::debug($res);
```

Result will be output of the query in the frontend. You can then execute it in MySQL for debugging.

Comment: How will I get the value for variable     `$xml_import_id` ?